# URL Rewrite in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

i want to use URL rewriting in this link and will apply to all website but it's not work why?
and what can i do if i want to using URL rewriting??

the link http://www.example.com/showpage/php?page_id = 98
and i want to be http://www.example.com/showpage/98

i test it in local but not work and test it online in my domain not work. if any tools must run in my domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^showpage/$ showpage.php?page_id=$1 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

$1 is not defined by a pattern. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^showpage/(.*)$ showpage.php?page_id=$1
```